# Accessing attribute of Object Pointer in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm stuck on a basic problem of trying to return an attribute from the an object pointer in c++.

My test code is below, I created an object from class node called Mynode, it has an attribute of value int 45.

I am expecting this code to return a pointer than then the value of data (45). but instead get a compile error

"error C2100: illegal indirection"

```
#include <iostream>

class node
{
public:
    int data;
    int* nextnode;

    node(int storedData)
    {
        data = storedData;
        nextnode = nullptr;

    }
};


int main()
{
    
    node Mynode(45);
    void* Node_PTR = &Mynode;
    int b =(*Node_PTR).data;

    std::cout << Node_PTR << std::endl;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "attribute"?

Comment: void* that's a void pointer, it should be node*

Comment: Change `void* Node_PTR` to `node* Node_PTR`

Comment: `(*Node_PTR).data;` can be simplified to `Node_PTR->data`, also consider renaming that variable to just `node` or `nodePtr`. It's bad-form to mix `PascalCase`, `camelCase`, and `UPPER_SNAKE_CASE` in identifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `void*` is a pointer to `void`. `void` is no type. It is the absense of a type. It has no member functions that you could call. A `void*` can point to any object and in past times there were some use cases of `void*` in user code. Not anymore. If you want a pointer to a `node`, that is `node*`.

Taking into account the comment on naming, using `struct` to reduce verbosity, and using in-class initializers and the member initializer list, because members are not initialized in the constructors body, your code can look like this:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Node {
    int data;
    int* nextnode = nullptr;  
    Node(int storedData) : data(storedData)
    {}
};    

int main() {
    Node node(45);
    Node* node_ptr = &node;
    int b = node_ptr->data;   
    std::cout << node_ptr << std::endl;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
}
```